# Error defining OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I came from [LazyInitializationException with hibernate and spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392915/lazyinitializationexception-with-hibernate-and-spring-mvc), but now the problem is this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:660)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:280)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.lookupSessionFactory(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:189)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.lookupSessionFactory(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:174)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

My `web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <!-- Hibernate OpenSessionInView filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and in my `servlet-context.xml` the Session Factory is defined like this:

```
...

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <!-- Annotated hibernate clasess -->
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="org.example.myproject.domains"/>

    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">${hibernate.pool_size}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.provider_class}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl}</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>

</beans:bean>

...
```

Why is this hapening? it seems like i have a wrong `*.xml` definition, can you help me please?

Comment: isn't the root-context.xml conflicting with the servlet-context.xml?

Comment: i don't know what is the purpose of that file (`root-context.xml`), is empty

Comment: try to remove it and test again

Comment: That didn't work, an 505 error, SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to delete the `root-context.xml`, because there is where you have to put all your beans to be shared and to make it **visibles** to `web.xml` and `servlet-context.xml`, and to the `hibernateFilter` that you have, because now he "is not seeing any `sessionFactory` bean. Look at this related post: [Spring, Hibernate Lazy Loading, sessionFactory, and OpenSessionInViewFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574552/spring-hibernate-lazy-loading-sessionfactory-and-opensessioninviewfilter?rq=1).

Good luck!